# Using BufferedImage to create an image in Java

Tags: java, arrays, rgb, bufferedimage

I am trying re-create an image using given 2D pixel arrays (rows, and columns) using the setRGB() method in BufferedImage.

Below is the follwing code:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(reconstructedJPEG[0].length, reconstructedJPEG.length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
//loop through redPixels[][] array
for(int row=0; row<redPixels.length; row++){
    for(int col=0; col<redPixels[0].length; col++){
        //call setRGB() on redPixels
        bufferedImage.setRGB(col, row, (redPixels[row][col]));
    }
}
```

The code above works, but I am not sure how I can also set the green and blue pixel arrays? 
Right now, its a very dull, dark red/purple image, that does no look like the original image.

Also, is there a another away I can form these arrays into a 1D image (which would be its raw pixels, red+green+blue components into one integer?

Thanks any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the individual color values for the 3 channels (red, green and blue) in one pixel using bitwise operators:

```
int rgb = (redValue & 0xff) << 16 | (greenValue & 0xff) << 8 | (blueValue & 0xff);
```

Then call `setRGB` with the composed value as parameter:

```
bufferedImage.setRGB(col, row, rgb);
```

---

The bitwise operation sentence can be cumbersome at first sight but it does the following:

- Take every channel value and make it 8-bit range based value (0, 255) using the `& 0xff` mask (the format [`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_RGB) expects channels to be 8-bit values)

  `redValue & 0xff`, 
     `greenValue & 0xff`,
     `blueValue & 0xff`
- Accommodates the channel values packing then into one 32 bit integer using the following layout:

  [image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I initially split the pixels like so: rgbPixels[j][0] = ((rawPixels[j]>>16)&0xff);
      rgbPixels[j][1] = ((rawPixels[j]>>8)&0xff);
      rgbPixels[j][2] = (rawPixels[j]&0xff);
      rgbPixels[j][3] = ((rawPixels[j]>>24)&0xff); Should I leave out the alpha value?

Comment: Yes, the alpha channel should be empty (ignored, in fact) for this format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason, my resultant image is completely scrambled up. I think it could be the fact i took in the alpha values initially, but did nothing with it, and now I am using the 3 RGB values only to form the image again. What should I do with that other array set, (i'd have to create a alpha array) ? Thanks

Comment: Unless I could alter the initial operations, and don't take in that alpha values. Thanks

Comment: Try ignoring the alpha and using: `rgbPixels[j][0] << 16 | rgbPixels[j][1] << 8 | rgbPixels[j][2]` only

Comment: Sorry, do you mean use >> rather than << because it is used to retrieve the values that way? I omitted the initial alpha channel, and I am still getting a fuzzy image result.

Comment: No, I mean the `<<` operator, because, as you stated before, the array `rgbPixels` already has the separated pixel components, so you have to combine them. Make a simple test by assigning a constant color to your  image like `r = 50`, `g = 200`, `b = 50`, you should see a green rectangle with that, if not, the problem may be in another part of the program

Comment: Test with: `bufferedImage.setRGB(col, row, 0x0032C832);`, (for a green rectangle) if this not work, test again but with: `bufferedImage.setRGB(col, row, 0xff32C832);`

Comment: Yes, I got a green rectangle from the 2 expressions. Now I should test with a constant? How could I implement that test?

Comment: sorry..Spoke too soon. I figured it out. The bit-shifting worked. I just was assigning the wrong array. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated